# Jasper Reports - Always align summary band to bottom

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

The summary band is always aligned to the bottom of the page when there is only 1 page. But when the summary band doesn't fit on the first page, it will be shown on the second page. If there is no Detail on the second page, only the summary band will be shown (together with the header and footer bands).

Is it possible to align the Summary band to the bottom of the page, just like the footer?

This would help me a lot in my current layout design.

Comment: Nobody with the same problem? If I use the lastpagefooter, this footer will not be placed on a new page, causing overflow in the detail band.

Comment: i am having this same problem, want to avoid summary band alone in second page if no detail or want to display last record in detail with sumary band when summary band doesn't fit on fist page...