# PrintWhenExpreesion for summary band always with detail band in same page

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

[image: First image working fine upto record of 9 if it exceed 10 record see 2nd image![][1]]PrintWhenExpreesion for summary band always come with detail band in last page dont want to print summary band alone in new last page

Comment: Can you add images to illustrate your needs?

Comment: Alex thank 4 reply the image is 2nd page with no deatil and 1st page has 9 record in detail.

Comment: For your reference this question also same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938133/jasper-reports-always-align-summary-band-to-bottom?rq=1

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more clearly?

Comment: No, summary should display last page only alex,if detail finished in 1st page and if summary has no space then it move to 2nd page like above image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14783/discussion-between-alex-k-and-aravinth)